# Do all humans have an identical nucleotide sequence for certain proteins, e.g haemoglobin?

Tags: genetics, proteins, gene, variant, nucleotide

All humans have the same sort of proteins in our bodies. Take haemoglobin for example.

Is the gene coding for haemoglobin in my body identical to everyone else's gene or is there slight variations in the nucleotide sequence?

Are there examples of proteins that are always completely conserved at the population level?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Humans have many variants

**There is variation.** The project I use to help understand this natural variation is [gnomAD](https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/).
**Using [VarMap](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/advance-article/doi/10.1093/bioinformatics/btz482/5514476) and a slightly out of date gnomAD file, I counted
16007805 protein-coding variants** across the human genome. This number will only go up over time.

Indeed, the 1000 Genome project found that on average each person has between 250-300 loss of function protein variants that are not found in their parents ([The 1000 Genomes Project Consortium, 2010](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature09534)).

This is an important concept for human health.
[ClinVar](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/clinvar/) is one of many projects that aims to catalogue and study when these variations lead to disease in a clinical context.
Another is the [100,000 genome](https://www.genomicsengland.co.uk/about-genomics-england/the-100000-genomes-project/) project by Genomics England which studies NHS patient data in cases of rare disease and cancer.

## Haemoglobin has variants, including disease variants

At the time of writing, HBA1 (haemoglobin alpha subunit gene) has 183 gnomAD variants and 17 pathogenic variants in ClinVar ([sourced from gnomAD](https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/gene/ENSG00000206172)).
Again, both of these numbers are likely to increase because the data will cover more people.

### Constraints on highly important proteins

But the underlying question is, I think, *"are there some proteins that are so important, that life keeps them highly constrained"* *i.e* any variation will lead to an invalid cell or a disease phenotype.
gnomAD attempts to add "constrained" metrics to each protein record, and some are more constrained than others.

For example:

- Haemoglobin scores a pLI of 0.01 (higher scores are more intolerant to variation, specifically loss of function variation).
- [p53](https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/transcript/ENST00000604348) is a gatekeeper of the cell cycle, mutants of which are common in cancer cells. It has a pLI score of 0.53 which means it is very intolerant to variation compared to haemoglobin.
- [Ribosomal protein L5](https://gnomad.broadinstitute.org/gene/ENSG00000122406) has a pLI of 0.998 implying it can tolerate little if any variation.
  The ribosome is critical in protein production, hence altering it may cause a complete breakdown of cellular life.

## Variation and Evolution

There is an almost philosophical difference between human variation and human evolution. Variation is a static snapshot of our protein sequence from individual to individual. Evolution in the sense of a [Dayhoff Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_matrix) requires looking back millions or billions of years by comparing similar protein sequences across many species.

Answer (score 33):

It is highly unlikely that there exist any protein that is made from completely identical nucleotide sequences across the entire human population. There will certainly be regions within a gene that are highly conserved, but there is little evolutionary pressure to conserve an entire gene's nucleotide sequence across the population.

This is in part due to the fact that different codons can translate into the [same amino acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table). So, even **if** a protein is (phenotypically) identical across the human population, the genes making that protein can use different sequences to code for the same amino acids. This alone can allow for an incredibly large number of possible gene variations that can code for an identical protein.

---

Related resources: [Neutral mutation (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_mutation) and the [neutral theory of molecular evolution (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_theory_of_molecular_evolution)

Comment: Haemoglobin has two distinct chains. It would be better to give separate numbers for each.

Comment: Apologies, I'll change the note to be more generic, as "variants" is not a precise descriptor and depends on context, such as in the point @David mentioned.

Comment: The fact that different codons can code for the same amino acid doesn't give anywhere _near_ "infinite possibility"! Most AAs are only coded for by 2 different codons, and only one is coded for by 6. Given a fixed length of gene, that is a far cry from infinite variability!

Comment: @terdon Hmmm... Even only considering two different codons for each amino acids for a small 100 amino-acids proteins, that gives 2^100 possibilities, a little in excess of 10^30... Not infinite, sure, but rather high !

Comment: Rather high indeed, absolutely :) Still a drop in the ocean when considering the full ~3billion bases in a human genome though. But yes, you're not wrong, even only the wobble positions give significant variability.

Comment: Anticodon are a funny example for conservation, because tRNA genes actually have a multitude of copies, and while itʼs true that thereʼs considerable negative selection on their anticodon loop, variability certainly exists — even here.

Comment: @GenTest This is a great answer, thanks. Just a heads up I edited the question to get rid of the term "mirroring". You might want to tweak your answer accordingly.

Comment: Variants are not limited to SNPs. There are rare instances (but a lot because of the size of the data!) of 2 nucleotide changes, and sometimes 3.

Comment: Edited answer to better suit edited question. Removed examples and language that may cause confusion. 1st time answering here, appreciate feedback. Please feel free to edit to improve answer, as original answer was provided in context as a reply to the OP's curiosity as a recent High School graduate and was structured as such.

Comment: @GenTest I'm glad you weren't put off by the comments and that you made the changes. I think the resulting answer is a great succinct answer to the question. Welcome to Bio.SE!

Answer (score 8):

At the whole-gene level, there is *likely* no absolute conservation of any human protein-coding gene at the population level, though there might be complete conservation between individuals. Keep in mind that most human genes are on the order of tens of thousands of base pairs [long](https://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/bionumber.aspx?&id=104316&ver=5), and only a portion of that length encodes functional motifs. There are, however, [ultra-conserved elements](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15131266) on the order of hundreds of base pairs that are identical between humans, rats, and mice.  Most of these elements are non-coding, and [some are transcribed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17785203) as functional ncRNAs.

Comment: *"At the whole-gene level, there is no absolute conservation of any human protein-coding gene at the population level,"* Are you sure about this? I wouldn't be surprised if there were a specific, very short gene with at least its coding sequence 100% conserved. Or even one with everything including UTRs conserved (perhaps a single-exon gene with no introns). I also wouldn't be surprised if no such thing existed, but you are explicitly ruling it out without a reference.

Comment: @terdon you're right -- I don't give a reference.  I should have qualified that first sentence with _"As far as I know, ..."_ or, as Gen Test said, _"It is highly unlikely ... "_

Comment: @terdon I haven't come across a whole protein that is completely "constrained", but there are indeed heavily constrained regions in both coding and non-coding regions.

Comment: @James neither have I. If I had to bet I'd say that there is no case of a protein coding gene whose coding sequence is 100% identical across all (healthy) individuals, but this is the human genome, so nothing can be ruled out! :)

Comment: @terdon My delay in response was me awk|sort|uniq-ing my gnomAD file. I have 18922 uniq UniProt codes, so there are a lot less than the complete proteome! That is more likely down to bugs than biology though! I'll report back when I am more confident.

Comment: @James ooh, that's actually a bit of a fun project. I have to run now, but give me a ping either in [The Biosphere](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere) or the [Bioinformatics.SE chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com//rooms/58858/bioinformatics). I'd love to see the results and would be happy to help out if needed.

Answer (score 0):

No gene and no base pair is immune to mutation. It is the natural selection pressure that keeps some gene relatively constant. Neutral mutations are not subject to pressure, so everything changes. And then, there are "almost neutral" mutations that also get passed by.